# Allow SQL Server Remote Connection

Tags: sql-server

I need to connect to remote SQL Server by an ip address with a port.

But when I ping to the ip address then that reply as well. But when I try to establish the connection that failed.

I tried with Management Studio and with command prompt too.

My command was:

```
sqlcmd -S [IP],[port] -U [user] -P [password]
```

The error report as follows :

> HResult 0x274C, Level 16, State 1
>   TCP Provider: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not 
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond.
>
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : A network-related or 
>   instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
>   Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see
>   SQL Server Books Online..
>   Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : Login timeout expired.

I would like to know that

1. is there any missing steps from my client side for which I am unable to establish the connection?
2. or this is the matter of server configuration (Allowing remote connection)

Comment: What **version** (2000, 2005, 2008 ??) and **edition** (Standard, Express, Enterprise) of SQL Server are you using??

Comment: i am really so sorry. actually i am new in .net. i don't know about what version and edition is using at the server end. but at the client end i am tring to connect with the sqlserver 2008 and express edition.

Comment: You need to find out that information. SQL Server **Express** for instance doesn't accept remote connections by default. It can be configured to do so - but it needs to be configured on the server side

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are actually missing the database name you would like to connect to:

EX: `sqlcmd -S [IP],[port]&#92;[DBNAME] -U [user] -P [password]`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to configuring the Windows Firewall to allow incoming connections on TCP Port 1433, you will need to start the SQL Server Browser service.  This service can be found on the Start Menu - Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 - Configuration Tools - SQL Server Configuration Manager.  Once there, click SQL Server Services on the left, then SQL Server Browser on the right.  This is disabled by default.

1. Right click SQL Server Browser and choose Properties
2. Click the Service Tab
3. For property Start Mode, choose Automatic
4. Click Apply
5. Click the Log On tab
6. Choose the appropriate account for log on (I used built in service account)
7. Click Apply
8. Click Start
9. Click OK

This solved my problem on Windows Server 2008 R2 with SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition.

Answer (score 0):

Check the firewall settings on the server that is actively hosting the database.  By default, Windows Server will block all remote connections to the Database Server.